# Insert Query with Subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to make an Insert query with a subquery. I have to insert other data apart from the subquery result. This is the query I have right now:

```
INSERT INTO articles (title,content,frontpage,date_created,userID,catID,sectionID) 
values("merijnmoetleren","blalblrsklfdkf", 1, "2010-01-23", 5, 2,
(SELECT id FROM sections WHERE name ="about")
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Is it working?  If it's not working, what error are you getting?  The only problem I see is you don't have enough Parentheses at the end of the statement: should be (SELECT id FROM sections WHERE name = "about"))

Answer (score 5):

See if this works

```
INSERT INTO articles ( title, content, frontpage, date_created, userID, catID, sectionID ) SELECT "merijnmoetleren","blalblrsklfdkf", 1, "2010-01-23", 5, 2, id FROM sections WHERE name ="about"
```

Comment: I fixed it, it was an error in another query who made this query fail.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO articles
  (title, content, frontpage, date_created, userID, catID, sectionID)
  SELECT "merijnmoetleren", "blalblrsklfdkf", 1, "2010-01-23", 5, 2, id
  FROM sections WHERE name = "about";
```

Comment: I fixed it, it was an error in another query who made this query fail.

Answer (score 2):

Put another closing paranthesis at the end.

Comment: Fixed that, but the problem isn't gone. The error is:

<code>#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT id FROM sections WHERE name ='about'))' at line 12</code>

Comment: I fixed it, it was an error in another query who made this query fail.

Comment: @rubinski_be - you should close this question so people aren't left wondering what's wrong with your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO articles ( title
                     , content
                     , frontpage
                     , date_created
                     , userID
                     , catID
                     , sectionID
                     ) 
              values ( "merijnmoetleren"
                     , "blalblrsklfdkf"
                     , 1
                     , "2010-01-23"
                     , 5
                     , 2
                     , (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM sections WHERE name ="about")
                     )
```

Comment: This query will add only 1 row if you want to add all from sections table use answer from Alex and Nicklamort